# Getting Invalid JSON error in Geckoboard php curl

Tags: php, curl, geckoboard

I am trying to add data in Geckoboard dataset using php curl but i am getting invalid json error. Please help me.

Please check my below code:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.geckoboard.com/datasets/sales.datasetidhere/data');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = array("articlePublished" => "6"); 
$data = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "Key:");

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
# Return response instead of printing.
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'data='.$data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r( $headers );
print_r( $response );
```

Here is the response: {"error":{"message":"Invalid JSON was received by the server."}}

Comment: `json_encodecode` is not a standard function. What does it do?

Comment: what is `json_encodecode` here? it should be `json_encode`

Comment: after using json_encode still not working

Comment: Was this ever solved? Having a similar issue.